# How to get rid of TrustedStreams.life malware?

Tags: malware, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 PC, and several members of my family who aren't terribly savvy about what notifications they click "OK" on. Result: I now have some kind of malware called "trustedstreams.life" that regularly pops up notifications ranging from annoying ads to fake virus warnings and pornographic images.

I've googled for solutions and found several sites that mention the "trustedstreams.life" malware, but none of the proposed solutions have worked:

- Opening browser settings and ensuring that trustedstreams.life is not authorized to pop up notifications (both Chrome and Edge)
- Resetting browser configuration (both Chrome and Edge)
- Checking for unknown browser extensions
- Checking for suspicious installed applications

All of the above yielded a clean bill of health; the malware must be residing somewhere else.

Any ideas where to look for it, or how to clean it?

Comment: This should work: https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-rescue-disk

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site.